# Difference between has and had in this context?

Tags: difference

Actual passage:

> Mr Somervell - a most delightful man, to whom my debt is great - was
>   charged with the duty of teaching the stupidest boys the most
>   disregarded thing - namely, to write mere English. He knew ho to do
>   it. He taught it as no one else has ever taught it.

```
First Year at Harrow by Sir Winston S. Churchill
```

I need to write this kind of sentence(below mentioned) in an answer to a question. Should I write has or had?

> Writer was taught by Mr Somervell - their English teacher, who taught
>   English like no else ***has/had*** ever did it.

Comment: This question is answered at http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19471/211388

Comment: However, I would also point out that you need to remove "ever did it" from the end making the sentence "Writer was taught by Mr Somervell - their English teacher, who taught English like no else had"

Answer (score 1):

The ending of your sentence might be

> ...like no one else *(ever)* **had**.
>   ...like no one else **has** ever taught English.
>   ...like no on else **had** ever done *(it)*.
>   .. like no one else **did**.